# SQLite 'GROUP BY' query rounding strangely

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, group-by

As part of an application that logs events and then charts them for the user, I'm running a query which runs through the last 24 hours, counts the records grouped into 2 hour intervals, and then shows them on a table (therefore making 12 entries).

The query I'm using is dynamically generated, but an example of one I ran last night is as follows:

```
Select strftime('%H', datetime(timestamp/1000, 'unixepoch')) AS Hour, COUNT(*) AS DateCount
FROM TableName 
WHERE Timestamp >= 1414605600000 AND Timestamp < 1414692000000 
GROUP BY (strftime('%H', datetime(timestamp/1000, 'unixepoch')) / 2) 
ORDER BY timestamp ASC LIMIT 0,12
```

What this does is return a list of results grouped by 2 hour intervals, named after the first hour. For example, if the query was ran at 6:05PM, the results should be:

```
Hour | DateCount
----------------    
18   | 3 records // Previous day
20   | 4 records // Previous day
22   | 2 records // Previous day
... pattern continues until the 4-6PM gap today...
16   | 3 records // Today
```

However, what's actually happening, is that the first result is returning an hour of 7. Effectively, the GROUP BY statement in this query is supposed to return every 2 hour interval, named after the first hour. So an interval of 4PM (16:00) to 6PM (18:00) should be called 16, but instead its coming out at 17.

Is this normal behaviour of a GROUP BY in SQLite? Am I asking too much of it by expecting this to work as I want it to?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
strftime('%H', datetime(timestamp/1000, 'unixepoch')) AS Hour
```

will return hour and not your "interval name". Your grouping clause use something like `Hour/2` so...

For instance:

```
 datetime        hour      hour/2
 --------------------------------
 17:00           17        8
 17:30           17        8
 16:00           16        8
 16:30           16        8
```

If you group this results, by `hour/2`, `hour` in resultset may be `17` or `16`, behavior undefined.

If you, however, create a `hour interval` field, than you solve (and simplify) your query:

```
Select strftime('%H', datetime(timestamp/1000, 'unixepoch'))/2*2 AS HourInterval, COUNT(*) AS DateCount
FROM TableName 
WHERE Timestamp >= 1414605600000 AND Timestamp < 1414692000000 
GROUP BY HourInterval
ORDER BY timestamp ASC LIMIT 0,12
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Forgive me for simplifying what is clearly a very well constructed post, but is the jist of this that by performing the "/2*2" operation on the original hour, you are able to ensure that 17 becomes 16, 14 remains 14, 3 becomes 2 etc, rather than the "undefined" behaviour as you described it?

Comment: `strftime("%H", ...)` will return integer. integer/integer performs integer division so, for instance, `17/2=8`. Indeed, `strftime("%H", ...)/2*2` will round hour to smaller "2 hour" interval.

Comment: Apologies for the time it took to reply, I've only now been able to get back to the build environment. Your solution worked perfectly, thank you very much :)!